# Why is javascript closing all html tags directly

Tags: javascript, html

I try to build some html-code by a javascript. But somehow all html-tags I open get closed directly by the javascript. How can I change this behavior?

Example of javascript:

```
function generateHTML() {
    var s='<table>';
    for(var i=0;i<max;i++) {
        s=s+'<tr><td>text</td></tr>';
    }
    s=s+'</table>';
    document.getElementById('tagID').innerHTML = s;
}
```

The final html-code looks like:

```
<table></table>
<tr><td>text</td></tr>
:
<tr><td>text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you creating the whole string and then writing it to the DOM. or writing as you go?

Comment: Please provide us with code where you generating HTML

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript. It seems like you are adding partial HTML to the DOM. You cannot create half of a DOM element. If you append partial HTML, the browser fixes it for you.

Comment: I edit my code of the example. My javascript is a function that I call by an onchange-event

Comment: Ohhh my god, that is embarrassing. The innerHTML-part was positioned in the wrong hierarchy in my more complex code................ I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

Save your final writing/appending of HTML until the end of your for-loop. Output your HTML more like this:

```
var s = '<table>';
for(var i=0; i<max; i++) {
    s += '<tr><td>text</td></tr>'; // append to s
}
s += '</table>'; // append to s

console.log(s);
```

**Output:**

```
<table><tr><td>text</td></tr><tr><td>text</td></tr></table>
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/budasa/embed?js,console)

Comment: Sorry, your advice doesn't solve my problem :-(    I still get a wrong output in my browser.

Comment: I saw your comment above about the hierarchy (I'm glad you fixed it). I've had to manually string-out tables before, and it helped me to compartmentalize each step. Something like startTable(), addRow(), endTable().